# Q: How to remove index and format output of table without leading whitespace for a dataframe object in pandas in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

## issue1

Q: How to remove index and format output of table without leading whitespace for a dataframe object in pandas in Python?

Code:

import pandas as pd

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Record Type': ['100', '200', '300'],'Value': [(1,2,3,4,5), (0,10), 1]},index = (['','','']))

print(df2)
```

I run it in Anaconda Spyder console.

And I expect it displays.

```
Record Type            Value
        100  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        200          (0, 10)
        300                1
```

However, it displays with a leading whitespace.

```
 Record Type            Value
     100  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
     200          (0, 10)
     300                1
```

---

Any replies will be helpful.

I post it in stackoverflow and Github.

stackoverflow:

Github:

https://github.com/40843245/Pandas/blob/main/Tutorial/Issues/issue%231.md

Although I have google it and find API of pandas, I just find a way to achieve it -- set the index as empty string ''.

Comment: `print(df2.to_string(index=False))` or in jupyter `from IPython.display import HTML ; HTML(df.to_html(index=False))`

Comment: Thanks to @mozway. It works for me to use df2.to_string(index=False). However, It returns a str object. I wanna get a dataframe object. How to achieve that? For more details, see the post Github as shown link inthe question.

Comment: Then use the html variant